# Issue fetching data from google analytics api

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, service-accounts

I've been following [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; PHP quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) in order to complete the set up for an API that will get data from a Google Analytics Report.

I've completed the first three steps as I created the service account, downloaded the private key, and installed the client library. I put the private key JSON file in the same directory as the `HelloAnalytics.php` sample file I got from the site. I used the view_id that is found in the view settings for the analytics campaign. I then changed the `$KEY_FILE_LOCATION` to the name of the private key file.

For some reason, when I run sample analytics file, I get the a 403 error  saying that permission has been denied even though I have added permission for the API inside of the campaign admin.

Did I skip a step? What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have missed a step.  Service accounts must be preauthorized.

> Add service account to the Google Analytics account
>
> The newly created service account will have an email address that looks similar to:
>
> quickstart@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>
> Use this email address to add a user to the Google analytics view you want to access via the API. For this tutorial only Read & Analyze permissions are needed.

Go to the Google analytics website in the admin section and add the service account email address as a user.   At the ACCOUNT level.

Comment: I did actually authorize the api with the Google Analytics site I just forgot to mention it. After trying to use OAUTH playground to test out the api and after adding the line `define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '/<credential_name>')`, I'm now getting a 401 error where it is saying that the authentication credential is missing. This is weird since I now am pointing to both the downloaded JSON for the client id/secret and the JSON file for the autogenerated private key. The issue seems to be related to a missing access token but I'm not sure how to get or add it in.

Comment: You dont get the access token the client library does.   You should only have one Json file the one from the service account credentials you created.   $KEY_FILE_LOCATION  You cant test service account with auth playground that is Oauth2 and completely different.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the second client ID file and I now only have the private key JSON file but I'm getting the same 403 error again. What could be going wrong?

Comment: You need to create oauth2 credentials and download the JSON file for that.

Comment: Ok, I was using the private key file instead instead of the client secret file from the OAuth client ID. I switched the $KEY_FILE_LOCATION to be the JSON file from the OAUTH 2.0 client ID but I'm getting the 401 again with the message: `Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.` The type of the client ID is web application so I'm not sure if that is causing the problem since its just being run from the terminal in a script. Is there anything else that should be done?